# How to perform operations in different thread then notify main thread in rxandroid?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I pretty much understand the concept of subscribe (any code below `subscribeOn` will be performed in that particular thread) and observe (same with `subscribeOn`) in rxandroid/rxjava.

What I want to happen is to perform long io operation in background thread then notify the main thread if the operations is finished. To do that, I'm thinking of having a `flatmap` which is subscribed in `Schedulers.io()` then observe a `subscribe` in `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`, something like this:

```
Observable.just(1)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .flatMap(o -> {
            longIO();
            return null;})
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(//i want to notify user here);
```

This is actually performing the `longIO()` in a different thread, thus not blocking the main thread, my problem is, this doesn't notify the main thread that `longIO()` is finished, note that android doesn't allow notifying user by creating `Toast` or `AlertDialog` if not in main thread. The code doesn't seem to pass through `subscribe`

**Note**: I used `just(1)` even though I don't use the integer 1 because I want the method inside `flatMap` to be performed. If I used `empty` it won't go through `flatMap`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34272955/schedulers-io-not-returning-to-main-thread?rq=1 Please refer this link

Comment: I'll check later if this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `flatMap` is `Observable`. If the `flatMap` returns a null `Observable`, the subscriber won't get notified. Change the return statement to `return Observable.just(null);`

But, it's preferred to use `Observable.fromCallable()` to wrap your `longIO()` method, so `just(1)` would be obsolete and code looks cleaner. Note: the return type of`fromCallable()` isn't `Observable`, so the subscriber would get notified even `null` is returned. It would look like:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        longIO;
        return null;
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are wrong in few things. IMO everything ABOVE `subscribeOn()` will be done in specific thread from thread pool. And of course everything BELOW `observeOn` should be pass into UI Thread.

Second thing - You cannot perform that your [flatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) operator is returning null. You need to return `Observable`. If you don't need to pass data you can use : `Observable.just(null) or Observable.never()`.

I think that better solution would be:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
        longIO();
        }
    })
    .startWith(new Object()) //if you want to run it once
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe();
```